# Python code for multiplying adjacent digits of a big number and finding maximum possible product, not giving desired result

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a **Python** code for finding maximum product we can get from 13 adjacent digits of a number. There is no error message, but this program is not giving the desired output. I am getting(in repl.it) `1` everytime, though it is clear that the answer is not `1`. I am new to programming.

> **My attempt**

I have converted the number into an string and stored it into a array to get element by element. The outer for loop traversing over all the numbers(last time when `i` have value `len(n)-12`, `i+j` will reach the last entry of the array. (Though the array stores the number in a reverse order, I haven't reversed it because, we don't need to).

```
n = "123899778978978787888787778788767677667"
arr = []
for i in range(len(n)):
  arr.append(int(n)%10)
  n = str(int(n)//10)

mul = 1
max_mult = 1
for i in range(len(n)-12):
  for j in range(13):
    mul = mul * int(arr[i+j]) 

  if(max_mult<mul):
    max_mult = mul
print(max_mult)
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why not working directly in integer type? why string/int/string ?

Comment: "this program is not giving the desired output" this isn't good enough. Please explain what you're expecting and what you're getting

Comment: with `for i in range(len(n)-12)`, `i never gets the upper value. Max is `len(n)-11``

Comment: You can get the list of digits simply by `arr = list(n)` (given that your `n = "123..."` is already string).

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks, I didn't knew that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Every time the output is showing `1`. Though it is clear that the result is not `1`. (I am using `repl.it` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic can be simplified somewhat using `zip`:

```
n_list = list(map(int, list(n)))
res = max(i * j for i, j in zip(n_list, n_list[1:]))  # 81
```

If you insist on using a `for` loop:

```
n_list = list(map(int, list(n)))
max_mult = 0

for i, j in zip(n_list, n_list[1:]):
    mult = i * j
    if mult > max_mult:
        max_mult = mult

print(max_mult)  # 81
```

Note you can modify your existing `range`-based iteration, but this is not considered Pythonic:

```
for i in range(len(n_list) - 1):
    mult = n_list[i] * n_list[i+1]
    if mult > max_mult:
        max_mult = mult
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `zip` is? when I can use it

Comment: Sure, `zip` [make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: This code not working :( Can you tell me where you have implimented multiplication of 13 consicutive digits?

Comment: @UnknownMathMan, In the `i * j` part of each loop.